# Write a logical proof to prove that the following argument is valid

Tags: logic

$$(\lnot t\land s)\to \lnot r  \\
(\lnot q\lor p)\to s  \\
\lnot t  \\
q\to t  \\
\therefore \lnot r\lor u.$$

I have attempted this proof a number of times for the past few hours, but have been unable to end with $\lnot r\lor u$. I know the $u$ is introduced via the law of addition.

Comment: Hint: consider writing $q\rightarrow t$ as $\neg t \rightarrow \neg q$.

Comment: $\lnot t$ and $q\implies t$ means $\lnot q$, which implies $s$, so $\lnot r$

Comment: What is $u$?  Not sure why but J.W. Tanner and Mauro curto seem to think $u$ is $s$?  Is it? Was that a typo?

Comment: @fleablood It is not a typo. All in know is that it is introduced somehow through the rule of addition.

Comment: I did make a mistake, I wrote (¬r ∨ s) insted of (¬r ∨ u) in step 13.

Comment: (u) is one of the disjunctives of the conclusion, since there is no way to derivate (u) from the premises the correct aproach to the derivation is to try to derivate (¬r) and conclude (¬r ∨ u) by the rule of introduction of the disjunction.

Comment: What do your attempts look like? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: What kind of proof system are you using -- some kind of axiomatic system, natural deduction, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Proof using natural deduction rules:

1. (¬t ∧ s) → ¬r - premise
2. (¬q ∨ p) → s - premise
3. ¬t - premise
4. q → t - premise
5. q - assumption
6. t - E→ in 4,5
7. ⊥ in 3,6 (close assumption 5)
8. ¬q - I¬ in 5
9. ¬q ∨ p - I∨ in 8
10. s - E→ in 2,9
11. ¬t ∧ s - I∧ in 3,10
12. ¬r - E→ in 1,11
13. ¬r ∨ u - I∨ in 12

Answer (score 1):

From $\lnot t$, $q\to t$, and modus tollens, we have $\lnot q$. Now since $\lnot q$, certainly, we have $(\lnot q\lor p)$, so $(\lnot q\lor p)\to s$ implies $s$ by modus ponens. Next, from $\lnot t$ and $s$, we have $(\lnot t\land s)$, which, in turn, implies $\lnot r$ by modus ponens. But if $\lnot r$, then, certainly, $\lnot r\lor u$.